# Propagating values up from cells to view controller

Tags: ios, swift

To start off, I have this person struct:

```
struct Person {
  var name: String
  var address: String

  init(name: String, address: String) {
    self.name = name
    self.address = address
  }
}
```

There's two properties that I want to **display** and allow for **edits** on a tableView.

I've got the following `UITableViewController` that uses dynamic prototype cells to display a bunch of info:

```
class TableViewController: UITableViewController {
  var person: Person!

  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    switch indexPath.row {
    case 0:
      guard let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellOne") as? CellOne else { fatalError() }
      cell.person = person
      cell.configure()
    case 1:
      guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CellTwo") as? CellTwo else { fatalError() }
      cell.person = person
      cell.configure()
    }
  }

  func updatePersonToServer() {
    Server.sharedInstance.updatePerson(person)
  }
  // other tableView methods...
}
```

Here's what one of the `UITableViewCell` subclasses:

```
class CellOne: UITableViewCell {
  @IBOutlet var nameField: UITextField!
  weak var person: Person?

  func configure() {
    nameField.text = person?.name
  }
}
```

The idea is that this tableViewController is passed a `Person` struct and displays it in a tableView. It allows the user to edit the information, and if they do, they can save the new stuff to the server.

I would like some opinions on the various ways to do this. One way I thought of doing is this:

```
func updatePersonToServer() {
  let nameCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! CellOne
  let addressCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(NSIndexPath(forRow: 0, inSection: 0)) as! CellTwo
  person.name = nameCell.textField.text!
  person.address = addressCell.textField.text!

  Server.sharedInstance.updatePersonToServer(person)
}
```

This looks ok for objects with relatively little fields, but in my app there are dozens of properties. I am looking for opinions on better ways to extract propagate information from dynamic cells back up to the view Controller to use.

Comment: You should use a delegation pattern; set your tableview controller as your cell's delegate and have it call back to a function in your tableviewcontroller. Why have you used the switch statement in the cellForRowAtIndexPath. Also it would be nicer to use a `didSet` function on the person property of your cell than to use the configure function

Comment: As an aside, Structs will synthesize their initializers for free: http://i.imgur.com/argioYs.png

Comment: @Paulw11 I used the `switch` statement because I wanted had two differently laid out cells. Nice call on the `didSet`, forgot about that. 

@Robert Thanks for the reminder!